# Elasticsearch: multiple languages in two fields when the query's language is unknown or mixed

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch, and I am not sure how to proceed in my situation.

I have the following mapping:

```
{
    "mappings": {

        "book": {

            "properties": {         
                "title": {
                    "properties": {
                        "en": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "english"
                        },
                        "ar": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "arabic"
                        }
                    }
                },

                "keyword": {
                    "properties": {
                        "en": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "english"
                        },
                        "ar": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "arabic"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A sample document may have two languages for the same field of the same book. Here are two example documents:

```
{
    "title" : {
        "en": "hello",
        "ar": "مرحبا"
    },
    "keyword" : {
        "en": "world",
        "ar": "عالم"
    }   
}

{
    "title" : {
        "en": "Elasticsearch"
    },
    "keyword" : {
        "en": "full-text index"
    }   
}
```

When I know what language is used in query, I am able to build query as follows (when English is used):

```
"query": { 
    "multi_match" : {
        "query" : "keywords",
        "fields" : [ "title.en", "keyword.en" ]
    }
}
```

Based on my current document mapping, how can I build a query if

1. the query language is unknown or
2. is mixed with English and Arabic?

Thanks for any input!

Regards.

p.s. I am also open to any improvement to the above mapping.

Comment: Have you tried using function_score query?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't add the fields you want to search on to the field list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**the query language is unknown**

You can use same multi match query but on all the fields.for eg,
Assuming you are using keyword analyzer

```
"query": { 
    "multi_match" : {
        "query" : "keywords",
        "fields" : [ "title.en", "keyword.en", "title.ar", "keyword.ar" ]
    }
}
```

**is mixed with English and Arabic**

You need to change the analyzer to standard and then you can perform the same query.

Thanks

Comment: dark_shadow, thanks sooo much for helping me! Two questions. First, I will add more languages. Any simplified query instead of listing all fields? Search against _all field? Sample code is really appreciated. You mean I need to change the analyzer to "standard" in the mapping in order to handle the situation in which the query language is mixed? Could you please update your post to show what you mean?

Comment: You can very well use _all field. It comes handy in those situations where fields on which query needs to be run are not known. In those standard analyzer are best. Please go through this link: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html for implementation.

Comment: In the 'fields' value you could also use wildcards so it would look like: `"fields" : [ "keyword.*", "title.*" ]`. Useful if you have more than two languages in multifield.